# Loading photo to canvas in onCreate didn't work

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-bitmap, oncreate

I have created my own view which including canvas.

I am starting an activity which loading bitmap from internal storage in oncreate and set this bitmap to canvas.

When I am trying to load photo to this canvas in function onCreate it did not work.

But when I tried to load this photo from onClickListener it is working.

What could be the problem?
How to load this photo to canvas automatically when activity is starting?

EDIT: 
The code is here:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign);
    signatureView = findViewById(R.id.signView);
    clearBtn = findViewById(R.id.clearBtn);
    acceptSignBtn = findViewById(R.id.acceptSignBtn);


    String fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("photo");
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(fileName);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[getIntent().getIntExtra("size", fis.available())];
        fis.read(byteArray);
        fis.close();
        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        photo = photo.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Log.i("TAG", "load done" +photo.getHeight());
        signatureView.setBitmap(photo);                        //There is no result, canvas stay clear

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    clearBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signatureView.clearCanvas();
            signatureView.setBitmap(photo);                     //after click photo appears
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post code so we can help better, and I have to say, probably you are trying to load the image into a 0wX0h view (onCreate, unless you have a fixed value in layout (not match or wrap parent neither weight)), on onClick it already have a size. To load into onCreate you will need to implement onMeasure and onLayout in the custom view.

Comment: I have edited and posted the code.

Comment: Are the implementation at signatureView.setBitmap(photo);  uses getWidth() and getHeight()? At onCreate it is 0 and 0, you may move your code to onLayout (call super.onLayout first)

Comment: Then you get with getMeasuredHeight() and getMeasuredWidth((

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the photo in onStart or onResume method (usually it should work in onCreate)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    //Your Image Loading Logic Goes Here
}
```

This method gets called after UI is completely visible.

Since your onClick is called after UI is completely created and visible.

Comment: When I put my loading image logic into this method app crashes when it comes to proper activity. Like the image loading code doesn't work in this method (Logs says that bitmap is null).

Comment: Load the bitmap in onCreate and setIt to the view in onAttach

Comment: I got the same result. It seems like the onAttachedToWindow method is executed before onCreate (or before oncreate method ends executing).

Comment: Are you loading in some fragment or directly into the activity

Comment: Or You could try putting it in onWindowFocusChanged

Comment: or try a postdelayed handler in oncreate